# 400 Error when visiting Django domain in production

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-settings

I have a Django app that I've deployed to production on Heroku. I have a settings package with different settings for local and production. In my local settings, I have `DEBUG` set to True and I'm able to both run the server and load the homepage. In my production settings module, everything is identical except for `DEBUG` being set to False and the addition of hostnames to `ALLOWED_HOSTS`. For some reason, when I try to access the site (either locally or on heroku) with the production settings, I'm getting a `400 Bad Request`. I think there might be something wrong with the format of my hostnames but I'm not sure:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['https://test_app.herokuapp.com/','http://127.0.0.1:8000/']
```

**What could be causing the 400 error? Should the urls be formatted differently?**

Comment: try to check your heroku logs `heroku logs -t --app app-name`

Comment: Have you tested with `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['test_app.herokuapp.com','127.0.0.1:8000]`?

Comment: @ABDULNIYASPM Yes, that also isn't working

Comment: @AnjaneyuluBatta Is that different from `heroku logs --tail`?

Comment: @loremIpsum1771 no, that's the same command but abbreviated.

Comment: You might also try simply `ALLOWED_HOSTS =['.herokuapp.com','localhost']`

Comment: @CharlieWeems Yes, thanks. That worked for the heroku url but not for the local url which is fine since there is a different settings file for running the project locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on the comments above:

Because Heroku uses different fully qualified domain names for review, staging, and production apps, I've generally found it best to use a wildcard by omitting the name of the app, but including `.herokuapp.com` (note the period).

Example: `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.herokuapp.com']`.

Comment: `['*']` defeats the entire purpose of the setting in production.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid So then using the `['*']` is standard practice?

Comment: Its very bad practice, especially in production.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I'll just leave it as `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.herokuapp.com']` then. Using the asterisk should probably be removed from the answer.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I agree with you (which is why I like to specify). The point of the other answer is that Heroku's custom domain service is supposed to provide this protection. However, it looks like they removed ['*'] from their official guide about three months ago: https://github.com/heroku/python-getting-started/commit/180cbfb1d26dd4bf66248ad385d5134ff07126d0